# Toggle ng-show on several divs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

So is there an angular.js best practice whereas if I have say 4 divs that all contain text and one is clicked, it shows a hidden part of div, then if another div is clicked, it closes the previous that is showing the 'hidden' part, but then shows the hidden part of the newly clicked div?

In the past, this took a bit of jquery code, but have been thinking of how I could combine ng-toggle with ng-show and ng-hide or is that simply overkill and there is a better practice for this?

Thanks much.

Comment: have you tried something ? Please paste the snippet in your question as well

Comment: Just started looking into it from this aspect. What is hanging me is the hiding when another div is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be the most optimized way to do this. If you don't understand anything you are welcome to ask me.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hiddenDivs = [ 
                          { id: 1, shown: false },
                          { id: 2, shown: false },
                          { id: 3, shown: false },
                          { id: 4, shown: false } 
                        ];
    $scope.showOwn = function(index) {
      for(var i=0; i<$scope.hiddenDivs.length; i++) {
        if(index === i+1){
          $scope.hiddenDivs[i].shown = true;
        } else {
          $scope.hiddenDivs[i].shown = false;
        }
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.my_div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="validateCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="hiddenDiv in hiddenDivs">
  <div class="my_div" ng-click="showOwn(hiddenDiv.id)">Content {{hiddenDiv.id}}
    <div ng-show="hiddenDiv.shown">Shown Inner Content {{hiddenDiv.id}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't the hidden divs function on this overkill?

Comment: You mean showOwn()? hiddenDivs is not a function, its just an array containing the properties of your divs which actually makes your life easier.

Comment: What I mean is, is there not a simpler way with ng-toggle and ng-show?

Comment: there is no ng-toggle by default, you simply use ng-show or ng-hide and set it to true or false using condition. But if you really want some toggle functionality you can check ou this toggle library for angularjs. http://zachsnow.com/#!/blog/2015/angularjs-ng-toggle/ I didn't work on it yet, but maybe it would be worth a try.